# Java Enum.name() unexpected result containing "?"

Tags: java, string, enums, case-sensitive

Today, one of my users has had my app crash on his device because of a strange error. This is the resulting message in my backend:

```
util.java.MissingResourceException: (Can't find bundle key med?um)
```

The bundle key is supposed to be "medium" and is build with the following (pseudo) code:

```
STAGE stage = something.getStage();
String stageValue = stage.name().toLowerCase();
```

where `STAGE` is:

```
public enum STAGE
{
    EASY,
    MEDIUM,
    HARD;
}
```

I was under the impression that the name() function would always return the value of the enum as it is in the code: "MEDIUM". How is it possible that it contains a questionmark?

Comment: The problem is that toLowerCase() isnt doing what you expect it to do.

Comment: nvm, did not see the duplicate tag yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be carefull about how you treat lower and upper case in java...

in places like Turkey where the alphabet has kind of similar vowels you can find

***I*** and ***İ***

see table below

[image]

so in that case you need to explicit use a Locale so java can consider some language especific convertions...

***MEDIUM*** is read as a turkey word will have a lower case like ***medıum*** (note the vowel has no upper dot), and this will make the app crash since you dont have such a value declared in the enumerator...